# How to print multiple pages with different ranges in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to print different ranges of some tabs of my Google Sheets workbook, I'd want for all of them to fit the page. So of the image below I would like to print a pdf of two pages with the separate tabs fitted to sheet.

I tried recording a macro for just one tab but couldn't even get that to work. Could anyone help me with this?

[Example of the two tabs I with corresponding ranges I want to print (fit page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeODM.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Can you create a new sheet that pulls in the data from the two ranges and format it for printing?

Comment: Any suggestion about how to add page breaks using formulas then? No sure if it was clear; I want to print the two respective tabs and ranges on two separate pages, with both of them 'fit to page'.
Also would like to automate this with something like scripts because it is a repetitive process (for different ranges that are calculated automatically)

Comment: Ah I also see when trying that loading ranges for print is not ideal